# JPA- Map the resultset from a stored procedure call to an entity class

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using eclipselink, and I have the following code to call a stored procedure:
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("exec ....");
 
    List list = q.getResultList();

Is it possible to map this list to a customized entity class that I created?

Comment: Could you provide the entity class you used?  Does it map to a real DB table or is it just used for retrieving the objects?  Your answer will help me solve my  [own problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28977819/1431979).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeQuery q= em.createNativeQuery("exec....",YOURENTITY.class);
List list=q.getResultList();